# Best books for solid foundation build up for python and java

Tags: self-learning, programming, java, python

Fellow programmers. I am currently learning java and python in my Master's degree (introduction) and I did those languages 2 years ago. And when I revisited for the units I feel like I have basic understanding but the foundation isn't concrete and keep messing up syntaxes between languages. So I want to read a book that will actually help me grow.

I thank you in advance for your recommendations :)

Comment: What are you studying (major field)? Why do you need both of these languages?

Comment: Books are good for learning in general how to talk about software systems and how to construct software systems, but to really learn a _language,_ you have to _speak_ the language. Practice writing code!

Comment: @Buffy My major field is software engineering

Comment: Asking for the "best" book is fruitless as you only get opinions. Few people answering know all the available books. Beware of any answer. For me, the best book is one that has a lot of programming exercises and several large projects. You learn programming by doing programming, not by reading a book.

Comment: I wrote my own.

Answer (score 1):

There is not best book.

**The answer to your question is "ANY".**

Just try any book for 1-2 chapters. Switch to another book, the a third. You will like 1 of the 3 more than the other two. Continue with it. There is no best book. Moreover, asking for recommendations sets up an expectation of something good that won't be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Books completely cannot provide a glance/solid foundation, as it depends on how you are utilizing the acquired knowledge from books in practical.

The book "**[Python Programming - An introduction to computer science](https://www.amazon.in/Python-Programming-Introduction-Computer-Science/dp/1887902996#customerReviews)**" - It offers you strong foundation on the subject and apt for reading by beginners with clear explanations.

**[Java - The Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt](https://www.amazon.in/Java-Complete-Reference-Eleventh/dp/1260440230)**.

Instead of downloading source code, its better to type and run in the IDEs. Half-learning is dangerous even for beginners.

The beginners of today will be the masters of tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

**Python: Violent Python**
A book about practical, hacky, fun uses of Python. Think variety, challenging and networking.

**Java: Effective Java**
A book about OOP best practices and designs in Java. Helps solidify simple concepts, introduces some design patterns and Java specific pitfalls. Think design, principles and ultimately enterprise architectures.